# Lucene 6 - how to intercept tokenizing when writing an index?

Tags: java, lucene, tokenize, analyzer

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39591094/apache-lucene-how-to-use-tokenstream-to-manually-accept-or-reject-a-token-when) says look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145688/how-to-tokenize-only-certain-words-in-lucene/24152554?noredirect=1#comment66511266_24152554)... but unfortunately these clever people's solutions no longer seem to work with Lucene 6, because the signature of `createComponents` is now

```
TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName)...
```

i.e. the `Reader` is no longer supplied.

Anyone know what the present technique should be? Are we meant to make the `Reader` a field of the `Analyzer` class?

NB I don't actually want to filter anything, I want to get hold of the streams of tokens in order to create my own data structure (for frequency analysis and sequence-matching).  So the idea is to use Lucene's `Analyzer` technology to produce different models of the corpus.  A trivial example might be: one model where everything is lower-cased, another where casing is left as in the corpus.

PS I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638200/how-to-get-a-token-from-a-lucene-tokenstream?rq=1): but once again we have to supply a `Reader`: i.e. I'm assuming that the context was tokenising for the purpose of querying.  When *writing* an index, although clearly the `Analyzers` in early versions were getting a `Reader` from somewhere when `createComponents` was called, you don't yet have a `Reader` (that I know of...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, again using the technique in the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145688/how-to-tokenize-only-certain-words-in-lucene/24152554?noredirect=1#comment66511266_24152554)... which is essentially to "interfere" in some way with the battery of `Filters` which are applied during the crucial method of `Analyzer`: `createComponents`.

Thus, my doctored version of an `EnglishAnalyzer`:

```
private int nTerm = 0; // field added by me

@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName) {
    final Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer();
    TokenStream result = new StandardFilter(source);
    result = new EnglishPossessiveFilter(result);
    result = new LowerCaseFilter(result);
    result = new StopFilter(result, stopwords);
    if (!stemExclusionSet.isEmpty())
        result = new SetKeywordMarkerFilter(result, stemExclusionSet);
    result = new PorterStemFilter(result);

    // my modification starts here:
    class ExamineFilter extends FilteringTokenFilter {
        private final CharTermAttribute termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
        public ExamineFilter( TokenStream in ) {
                super(  in);
          }         
        @Override
        protected boolean accept() throws IOException {
            String term = new String( termAtt.buffer(), 0, termAtt.length() );
            printOut( String.format( "# term %d |%s|", nTerm, term ));

            // do all sorts of things with this term... 

            nTerm++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    class MyTokenStreamComponents extends TokenStreamComponents {
        MyTokenStreamComponents( Tokenizer source, TokenStream result ){
            super( source, result );
        }
        public TokenStream getTokenStream(){
            // reset term count at start of each Document
            nTerm = 0;
            return super.getTokenStream();
        }
    }
    result = new ExamineFilter( result );
    return new MyTokenStreamComponents(source, result);
    //
}
```

The results, with input:

```
    String[] contents = { "Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall,", "Humpty Dumpty had a great fall.", ...
```

are wonderful:

```
# term 0 |humpti|
# term 1 |dumpti|
# term 2 |sat|
# term 3 |wall|

# term 0 |humpti|
# term 1 |dumpti|
# term 2 |had|
# term 3 |great|
# term 4 |fall|

# term 0 |all|
# term 1 |king|
# term 2 |hors|
# term 3 |all|
# term 4 |king|
# term 5 |men|
```

...